# Serverless Framework with Multiple Api Gateway and Single Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless-framework

I have a single lambda function that needs to be accessed by an application and by the testers. The application lives in a vpc which requires my api gateway to be private and have vpc endpoint. While the testers needs to access the api gateway on their machines through postman.

On my serverless.yml I have this code

```
provider:
  name: aws
  endpointType: private(application) / edge(testers)
  vpcEndpointIds: id's
  resourcePolicy: sourceVpc(application) / sourceIP(testers)
```

But it applies to both http event on my lambda.
Is it possible to have two api gateway with different resource policies and endpoint type (private and edge) that integrates to a single lambda function?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways imho:

1. Make your endpoints private and then add 2 api keys (if you just want to have separate endpoint that will be accessed only by devs).
2. Try to deploy your app to different stages (--prod, --sandbox).

It's not the best answer but maybe it will help you to did deeper on this subject.